# Flex layout containg a flex scroller

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a page layout based on flex, and I'm wanting to insert a scrollable pane of items into the `.main` container. But the `.scroller` isn't being restricted by the parent. Is there a way to get the `overflow-x: auto` scrollbar to appear?

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  outline: 1px red solid;
}

.menu {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  outline: 1px green solid;
}

.scroller {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scroller li {
  margin: 0 6px;
}

// other styles

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; 
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
  </ul>
  <section class="main">
    <h1>Page contents</h1>
    
    <h2>Slideshow</h2>
    <ul class="scroller">
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff" /></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</article>
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/cloakedninjas/pen/MxqMbK)

Comment: min-width:0 to main element

Answer (score 0):

overflow-x: auto; needs to go on main, not scroller

Comment: Nope, I only want the `.scroller` to get scrollbars. But no matter - Temani located the solution... `min-width: 0;` on `.main`